# How to use .trim().length in .cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have written following condition in .cshtml page but it is not working

```
@if (row.item.FullName.Trim().length <= 0)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "UsersInfo")
            }
            else
            {
                <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "UsersInfo", new { id = row.item.UserId }))'>Contact</a>
            }
```

My requirement is if `FullName` contains empty then link visible for Create else Edit. It is giving me following

Error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

if i use `@if (row.item.FullName == "")` then it will display following screen

```
<img src='http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/Uploads/5038017/screen.png'/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.item.FullName)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.item.FullName))
```